# Запятая перед "и" в моей фразе

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Нужна ли запятая перед первым "и" во фразе
"Снова и снова, и снова"?

Answer (score 1):

Как хотите.
Запятая может стоять по правилу  о запятых перед повторяющимися союзами ([§ 13 пункт 1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101)), а может не стоять -- по правилу, что "если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом *и*, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом и с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится" (там же, пункт 8).